# Trouble with the Bprojection addon

Tags: add-on

I've installed my first addon, [Bprojection](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/bprojection).

When I tried testing it out on a copy of my original work it only had the option of *add Bprojection plane*?
I have a UV mesh of the object ready but I do not have a Multires Bake Displacement map because I do not have a multires modifier. How do I get a displacement map and how do I get Bprojection to work like [this](http://vimeo.com/38400773#at=0)?

~the BProjection thing is at the bottom of the tool section in the bottom right corner:
[image]

Comment: judging by lack of response here, it seems those of us who've read this question haven't used the addon. Perhaps you might read through the [support thread for the addon](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?248870-BProjection) at BlenderArtists, where the addon author frequents. On the last page of that thread @craig_jones  mentions that the addon is now slightly redundant and why.

Comment: Please explain "_what you want to accomplish_" rather than "_how you want to accomplish it_". (As zeffii hinted towards) [BProjection is dead](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?248870-BProjection&p=2375447&viewfull=1#post2375447), due to the inclusion of  [stencil mapping](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.67/Paint_System#Stencil_mapping).

Comment: Well, what I want to accomplish is making a skin texture, that can carry onto cycles. What I mean by skin texture is, get very detailed parts of the skin like freckles and red areas around the nose and eyes, and a perhaps a blue hue near the eye bags.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an addon that is no longer actively developed, and for which the author recommends that you use the built in [Stencil Mapper](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?296949-Stencil-Mapping-Tutorial).

Comment: The addon should probably be removed from [scripts lists](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts) too.